# Rejecting form post after is_valid

Tags: django

I'm attempting to overwrite the RegistrationView that is part of django registration redux.

https://github.com/macropin/django-registration/blob/master/registration/backends/default/views.py

Essentially, I want to implement logic that prevents the registration from happening if some condition is present. Checking for this condition requires access to the request.

I'm thinking that I might be able to subclass the register function within this Class based view.

```
  def register(self, form):

        #START OF MY CODE
        result = test_for_condition(self.request)
        if result == False:
            messages.error(self.request, "Registration cannot be completed.", extra_tags='errortag')
            return redirect('/access/register')
        #END OF MY CODE
      
        site = get_current_site(self.request)

        if hasattr(form, 'save'):
            new_user_instance = form.save(commit=False)
        else:
            new_user_instance = (UserModel().objects
                                 .create_user(**form.cleaned_data))

        new_user = self.registration_profile.objects.create_inactive_user(
            new_user=new_user_instance,
            site=site,
            send_email=self.SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL,
            request=self.request,
        )
        signals.user_registered.send(sender=self.__class__,
                                     user=new_user,
                                     request=self.request)
        return new_user
```

What is the correct way to do this using class based views? I've worked almost exclusively with function based views so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, it is recommended to subclass "AsbtractBaseUser" and "BaseUserManager" for user management in Django.

In CustomUserModel, you can define required fields added to the existing fields from BaseUserManager.

In CustomUserManager, you can override create_user, create_staff_user, create_superuser, and save_user. You can define a few conditions that should be checked before registering the user and also you can add permissions or groups to the user based on the role in the "save_user" method.

Create CustomRegistrationSerializer, that controls the fields that need to be displayed on the registration page, and validation of those fields can also be defined.

In POST method of CBV, you can check condition that requires "request" before serializing data. If condition is met, you can continue with serializing and saving otherwise, you can return appropriate response.

Django : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model